When submitting my manuscript to a publisher, how should I answer "What are you prepared to do to market your book?"?
I am a new author, preparing to submit my manuscript. The publisher's submission form has asks a question I am somewhat confused on. "What are you prepared to do to market your book?" One of the reasons I chose this company was because they claim to work closely with their authors and have a strong marketing campaign. This is still new territory to me, so I may be missing something. How should I answer this question, and what is the company trying to determine from me?

I suspect that's rather a trick Question, intended as much to test your own experience as anything else. 'I'd be happy to go on a reading-and-signing tour…' is a very different Answer from 'I'd be happy to go on a reading-and-signing tour, and who is picking up the tabs?'

Today, a significant part of the marketing effort for a book must be undertaken by the author. It is quite normal that publishers discuss this aspect with you. Some examples for what authors may do are:

actively build and expand your social media presence and create a following
approach media such as tv, radio, newspapers, blogs etc. and give interviews or ask for reviews
do readings/signings in libraries and bookstores
if you write non-fiction, holding lectures in your field of expertise
etc.

This (or certain aspects of this) are called platform. As a non-fiction author you absolutely must have it or you might not get a publishing deal. For fiction, it wasn't a requirement in the past, but with the success of self-publishing authors who are very present on social media it is becoming more and more important for traditionally published authors too.
It is important, though, that you don't lie here and promise what you aren't willing or able to do.

There are few things that writers can do as part marketing their books.
Public Readings and Book Signings: self-explanatory; it also means that author is on the road, going from bookshop to bookshop. Maybe for weeks.  One of Brandon Sanderson’s lectures at BYU details his roadtrip experience going up and down the west coast, pressing the flesh and reading the word.
Interviews: sitting for interviews by book-related journalists and influencers.  I gather these are more common now with the wide spread adoption of remote video like zoom and webex.
Social Media:  Create writing related and story related content for social media.  This could be like writing articles on some aspect of the craft of writing or story telling — this can establish interest by other writers that found the article useful and informative, then they might talk up this new novel that you wrote. Or it be reviews of current novels, putting your name out there in the world — I liked that review of such and such, maybe I’ll give that writer a try.
Panel:  This might be duplicative with the first item.  But they are held as conferences and genre-related conventions.  The goals is to get your name and your face in front of potential readers so they’ll be positively inclined to buy your book. This is also part of the strategy with social media.  It’s not always about pushing your book, but offering something of value for free that results in a reciprocal transaction — buying your book.
All these things take effort and time. It sounds like they trying to gauge your willingness or ability to participate.  I doubt it will enter into their decision making on whether to buy the book or not. Good writing sells. It might affect the size of the advance since the less you participate in the marketing that means they are paying someone to do the necessaries.
If you are in doubt, tell them the truth — you’re aren’t sure what is involved.  If you have health conditions that restrict your ability to travel or you have job commitments that limit your availability, that question is a great opportunity to share those details.

"I'm willing to do everything I can and everything I know how to do."
